# C# 6 getters and setters

Tags: c#, getter-setter, c#-6.0

I am using C# 6.0 to create getters and setters of properties in a class like this:

```
private int _id { get; set; }

public int Id => _id;
```

But the compiler says:

> Property or indexer 'Id' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

How can I fix it without creating getters and setters like this:

```
private int _id { get; set; }

public int Id 
{
   get { return this._id; }
   set { this._id = value; }
}
```

Comment: @Dr.Fre, this is compiler feature, not framework version based

Comment: As a rule, with this kind of thing, if you find yourself guessing wildly and using language features at random, you should go back and start over by imitating code written by people who know the language well.

Comment: I thought maybe in C# 6 you don't need two separate fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shorthand syntax with => only constructs a read-only property.

```
private int _id;
public int Id => _id;
```

This is equivalent to auto-property which is read-only:

```
public int Id { get; }
```

If you want your property to be both settable and gettable, but publically only gettable, then define private setter:

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

That way you don't need any private field.

Comment: I thought maybe in C# 6 you don't need two separate fields?

Answer (score 3):

With

```
private int _id { get; set; }
```

you are creating a property `_id` with a getter and a setter.

With

```
public int Id => _id;
```

You are creating a property `Id` that has only a getter and returns the value of property `_id`

I think you are mixing up how to take advantage of automatic properties, because this

```
private int _id { get; set; }

public int Id 
{
   get { return this._id; }
   set { this._id = value; }
}
```

creates two properties: `_id` with auto-generated getter/setter and `Id` with explicit getter/setter that just call the corresponding getter/setter of `_id`.

Without the automatic property feature, you had to write this:

```
private int _id;

public int Id 
{
   get { return this._id; }
   set { this._id = value; }
}
```

Here, `_id` is a field and `Id` is a property.

Answer (score 2):

This is the C# 7.0 syntax, just in case you want to keep the private field:

```
public int Id 
{
   get => _id;
   set => _id = value;
}
private int _id;
```

Which is very useful for giving full access to some of the properties of a wrapped object:

```
private Person wrappedObject;

public string Name
{
   get => wrappedObject.Name;
   set => wrappedObject.Name = value;
}
```